# PayPal Checkout.js functions data vs actions variables?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to add PayPal button using `checkout.js` and a lot of examples need a function with such declaration:

```
function (data, actions) {
    // ...
  }
```

Doing some debugging, I found that `data` and `actions` variables have exactly the same properties on them. This is kinda weird and the question I am left is, what are the purposes of these two? Cause they sound to be very different.

That's some excerpt of my findings, deeper properties are also the same:

[image]

Comment: Check [PayPal Checkout API](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Comment: I did look at it, but I didn't find an answer